# Change user password in the wordpress database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am forcing the user to change the password the first time they access the site in wordpress.
In the table wp_users I added this field `status tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1`.
When the user logs in, I query the database and if the status field is -1, show the form for changing the password as follows:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<php
if($_SESSION['status'] == '-1'): ?>

<div class="alteracao">
    <form class="alteracao-signin">       
        <h2 class="alteracao-signin-heading">Tem de alterar a sua senha.</h2>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="senhaatual"  placeholder="Senha Atual" required=""/>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="senhanova" placeholder="Nova Senha" required=""/> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="senhaconfir" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" required=""/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button>   
    </form>
</div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Then to change the password in the database I am doing it this way:

```
$senhaatual = $_POST["senhaatual"];
$senhanova = $_POST["senhanova"];
$senhaconfir = $_POST["senhaconfir"];
$status = '1';
$id_util = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];

$senhafinal = password_hash($senhanova, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = 'UPDATE wp_inf.inf_users SET user_pass= ?, status= ? WHERE ID = ? '; 
    $conn->prepare($query)->execute([$senhafinal, $status, $id_util]);
```

It does not return any error in the browser console but it does not update the data in the database.

Can you help?

Comment: There should be `$senhafinal` in column `user_pass` shouldn't it? Check SQL errors.

Comment: @pavel I already corrected it, it was when copying I didn't notice that I had made some changes to the sql of the php page. But still does not update

Comment: In your HTML you have 3x `name="senha"`. `name` attribute is send into `$_POST`, not IDs. And the last logic mistake, you never check if passwords are correct, just assigning them into variable.

Comment: @pavel Yes, I know I don’t check, but I’ll check. But as I was not doing the update I removed the verification of passwords. I am trying to solve the update part of the database first.

Comment: `$senhanova` is empty (if you'll check PHP error log or write down PHP errors into site, you'll find that there are undefined keys in `$_POST` due to my comment above).

Comment: @pavel I updated the question with the correction in the form and with the php, but it does not change the values ​​in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all these passwords variables empty.

```
$senhaatual = $_POST["senhaatual"];
$senhanova = $_POST["senhanova"];
$senhaconfir = $_POST["senhaconfir"];
```

It's because there are no elements with `name="senhaatual"`, `name="senhanova"` and `name="senhaconfir"` in your HTML.

Plus `form` hasn't `method="post"` and is send by GET method by default.

Working code would be

```
<form method="post">
    ...
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senhaatual" id="senhaatual"  placeholder="Senha Atual" required=""/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senhanova" id="senhanova" placeholder="Nova Senha" required=""/> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senhaconfir" id="senhaconfir" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" required=""/>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: With the corrections you indicated, in the comment and here in this answer, you do not update the data in the database.

Comment: @Pinto no, that's all you need to change. If it still doesn't work you have there any more mistakes. Please check error log and/or set error reporting on. Combination of `method=post` and correct `name`s is what you're looking for to use `$_POST['name']` variables.